# Similar of JavaScript parent function names

Tags: javascript

Tell the similar functionality like parent

```
parent.document.getElementById(source).innerHTML
```

must equal to

```
other-function-name.document.getElementById(source).innerHTML
```

Comment: could you please reformulate your question ? it really doesn't make sense right now

Comment: Doesn't he just mean: Are there other objects (globally available object instances, like `parent`) that have a `document` property that he can call `getElementById` on?

Answer (score 0):

parent is not a function. It is an object most probably a window object. And a child object inside that is referenced by using the code.

See

[window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent)

> Returns a reference to the parent of
>   the current window or subframe.
>
> If a window does not have a parent,
>   its parent property is a reference to
>   itself.
>
> When a window is loaded in an
>   , , or , its
>   parent is the window with the element
>   embedding the window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if an object has a "document" property that is a document node, you can do:

```
(typeof obj.document == "object" && obj.document.nodeType == 9)
```